# Is range of completely continuous of bounded set finite dimensional set?

Tags: operator-theory, differential-topology, banach-spaces, compact-operators, dimension-theory-analysis

Define of completely continuous operator : $L$ is continuous operator and map bounded set to [relatively compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relatively_compact_subspace) set , then $L$ is completely continuous operator.

Let $\Omega$ is a bounded set of  Banach space and $L$ is completely continuous.
Is  $L(\Omega)$  finite dimensional set ?

Comment: What is the definition of *map bounded*?

Comment: @EnjoysMath   $\max_{x\in\Omega} ||x||<\infty$

Comment: What you define is usually referred today as a compact operator. Completely continuous operators are defined a little differently. Check this article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_operator#Completely_continuous_operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Here's a prototypical example. I'll leave details of proof.

Suppose that $H$ is a Hilbert space with an orthonormal basis $(\phi_n)$ and let $(\lambda_n)$ be a sequence of numbers converging to $0$. Define

$$T f = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lambda_n (\phi_n,f) \phi_n.$$

Then $T$ is compact (the image of any bounded set is relatively compact).

Note that the range of $T$ is finite dimensional if and only if all but finitely many $\lambda_n$'s are zero. In fact, any self-adjoint compact operator on $H$ is of this form.

I'd like to add that your intuition was in the right direction, though, as $T$ is the limit in the operator norm of the sequence of the finite-rank operators $T_N$ obtained by taking only the first $N$ summands, and more generally, the linear space of compact operators is the closure of the finite rank operators.

Comment: Could you give me a detail proof ? I can understand why the image is compact.

Comment: If $T$ has finite rank, it is compact. Suppose that $T$ is the limit in the opoerator norm of a seqeunce of compact operartors $(T_n)$. Let $(x_m)$ be a bounded seqeucne. Then by standard diagonalization we can find a subseqeunce which we also denote by $(x_m)$ such that, $(T_n x_m:m\in{\mathbb N})$ converges for every $n$. Use this to show that $(Tx_m)$ is Cauchy.